# Git ssh forward-agent not being used on remote server

Tags: git, ssh

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype auth-agent@openssh.com rchan 2 win 65536 max   16384
debug1: channel 1: new [authentication agent connection]
debug1: confirm auth-agent@openssh.com
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
```

I can't seem to solve why my forwarded key appears to not be being used when calling bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23171517/3134155).

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_key
```

Solved my problem.