# SSH Agent Forwarding not working

Tags: github, ssh, capistrano3

I'm having an hard time trying to configure Capistrano 3.1 to deploy an app hosted on Github.

I'm following [Capistrano Documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/) and I have successfully completed the first step (SSH keys from workstation to servers) and on the second one (From our servers to the repository host) I'm able to successfully run `ssh -A deploy@one-of-my-servers.com 'git ls-remote git@github.com:my_user/my_repo.git'`:

```
18f38afz261df35d462f7f4e2ca847d22f148a06    HEAD
18f38afz261df35d462f7f4e2ca847d22f148a06    refs/heads/master
```

however, `ssh deploy@one-of-my-servers.com 'git ls-remote git@github.com:my_user/my_repo.git'` fails:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Capistrano docs suggests

> If you get the error "host key verification failed." log in into your server and run as the deploy user the command ssh git@github.com to add github.com to the list of known hosts.

SO, I tried so but I get

```
ssh git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.131' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

And I'm basically not able to successfully access the Github repo.

SSH documentation states:

> ```
> -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This
>          can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration
>          file.
> ```

How can I  specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file?

My local machine runs Mac OSX Mavericks.
The VPS runs Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks.

Comment: See another possible cause (and solution):
https://serverfault.com/questions/404447/why-is-ssh-agent-forwarding-not-working#answer-1032309

Comment: > `ssh -A deploy@one-of-my-servers.com` Just FYI, the domain `example.com` is reserved exactly for use cases like this. So whenever you need an example domain, you can use `example.com` and rest assured you are not using an actual domain and you are following the ICANN guidelines.

Answer (score 85):

Do you have your ssh key added to the list of agent identites ?

You can check with `ssh-add -L` , you should see the key your are using to connect to github :

```
$ ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa AAAAB3N.....0VmSiRvTzBrbU0ww== /Users/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you don't see the ssh key you use for github or a message like

> The agent has no identities.

Then you should add your key with :

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(replace with the path to the key you use for github)

See the [ssh-add doc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add) for more info

Comment: This solved my issue! Thanks! If it were my question I would accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! is it possible that i was getting this issues because i copy pasted the keys files instead of creating them using the bash commands?

Answer (score 38):

Add following lines to .ssh/config file on your local computer

```
  Host Server_Address
     ForwardAgent yes
```

Check your local key whether listed in ssh-add list or not with

```
ssh-add -L
```

If not add key to SSH Agent

```
ssh-add -K
```

Connect to Remote Server

```
ssh -v username@Server_Address
```

Check SSH Agent forwarding is enabled by running following command. It should list a socket file

```
echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

Run connection test against GitHub

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Run ls remote test against targeted git repository

```
git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:account/repo.git
```

Finally logout and run following from your local machine

```
cap production git:check
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer! Thanks

Comment: Hm, what if everything checks out (SSH key is added to agent and verified, agent forwarding is enabled and verified on the remote host) and I still get `Permission denied (publickey).` when testing `ssh -T git@github.com` (actually `gitlab.com` in my particular case)? It only does not work on a particular host though.

Comment: Take a look at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/171. There are some useful recommendations. Start with running `ssh -vT git@github.com` to see more details

Comment: One side-note: per `ssh_config(5)`, "For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used."... I had a host-specific `ForwardAgent yes` in my ssh config, which I thought would override the `ForwardAgent no` I had up top, but that's not how it works! I moved `ForwardAgent no` to the bottom of `.ssh/config`, and I've confirmed it's still disabled by default, but now the per-host enabling works.  Also, `ssh-add -K` is not only MacOS-specific, but may well be undesired. "When adding identities, each passphrase will also be stored in your keychain" -- I don't want that!  YMMV.

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to ~/.ssh/config

```
Host one-of-my-servers.com
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I forgot to mention I added it already ```Host 111.222.222.44:24566
  ForwardAgent yes```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another cause: If the target host's fingerprint doesn't match with your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, SSH automatically disables Agent Forwarding.

The solution is:

```
$ ssh -A -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  my-target-host
```

Comment: You probably want to just add the host key with `ssh-keyscan`

Comment: `ssh-keyscan` would be a good solution when you plan to manually execute `ssh` later. For an automated job (cron job, CI/CD pipeline script, etc.) which contains `ssh`, you wouldn't want to deal with `ssh-keyscan`.

Comment: For an automated job you want to verify the fingerprint, or use SSHFP / SSH certificates. Overriding security checks is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure why but previously using `ForwardAgent yes` was enough IIRC. I had to add `AddKeysToAgent yes` additionally to make this work. This basically automates what `ssh-add` does AFAICT. So a possibly better answer to this question than those so far might be:

```
Host Server_Address
   ForwardAgent yes
   AddKeysToAgent yes
```