# Capistrano and GitHub Private Repo – Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, ssh, capistrano, linode

I've inherited a Rails project, hosted on Linode.

The previous developer was using a BitBucket repository, along with Capistrano for deployments.

I've since setup a private repository on GitHub, and I'm trying to get the Capistrano recipe to work. I'm having no luck. I continue to get a publickey error during deployment.

Here are the steps I've taken –

1. Updated the Git remote (origin) URL on the Linode server to point to my new repository
2. Updated the repository reference in the Capfile, to reference my new repository
3. Ensured `ssh_options[:forward_agent]` was set to true in the Capfile
4. Generated an SSH key locally (id_rsa.pub) and added it to my user account in GitHub
5. Executed the `ssh-add` command, to ensure the identity was added for auth agent
6. Ran `ssh -T git@github.com` to confirm ssh was properly setup locally
7. Logged into my Linode server and ran `ssh -T git@github.com` to ensure it was working also

Additionally, just in case the forward_agent property wasn't working, I even tried generating an SSH key on the Linode server, and adding it to GitHub as well. No luck.

After all of this, when I run `cap deploy`, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Below is the recipe I'm using –

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "----SERVER IP----", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "blog"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/blog"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:--MY USERNAME--/blog.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do; end
  task :stop do; end
  task :restart, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
    run "touch #{deploy_to}/current/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/blog"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/public/avatars #{release_path}/public/avatars"    
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong – any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### UPDATE

I've also ensured the following was added to my local ~/.ssh/config file...

```
Host mydomain.com
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: Can you try running "ssh-add" on your local machine, then re-running `cap deploy`? More info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)

Answer (score 21):

Today I found the root cause on MAC. My ssh key was not added to the authentication agent so the key was not forwarded. The solution was to execute the following command:

```
 ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

(or `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` if you use rsa key)

To remove all the ssh keys added to agent

```
ssh-add -D
```

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the following line to your Capistrano script, this will explicitly tell Capistrano what key it should be using.

```
set :ssh_options, { 
  forward_agent: true, 
  paranoid: true, 
  keys: "~/.ssh/id_rsa" 
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when I had set all of the pieces correctly, was running everything from command line correctly, and still was getting a password challenge from the deployment server. For example, ssh -A deploy@server 'git ls-remote git@github.com:x/y.git HEAD' worked, but cap deploy did not.

Comment: @jjk that sounds like the ssh key you are using is not placed in the authorized_keys file for that user?

Comment: I was following

[link](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/)

I believe that I updated the authorized_keys file for that user using ssh-copy-id, but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 9):

If you're still stuck I answered a similar question as yours here: [SSH Agent Forwarding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522081/ssh-agent-forwarding-not-working/23171517#23171517)

Check if your key is added to the list of agent identities with `ssh-add -L`.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly I could SSH from dev machine to the staging machine and also SSH from staging machine to github.com.

However cap deploy failed doing the git clone

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

however the git ls-remote worked which is strange.

If I added this to my config on the staging machine it works

```
Host github.com 
    Hostname github.com 
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git 
    User git
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the only way it has deploy was:

adding the local id_rsa to the server

`cat ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub | ssh -i /Users/jasmo2/Documents/AWS-keypair/designmatch.pem ubuntu@52.37.202.32 "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"`

after typing the command. Is preferable to set the set [:ssh_options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22978858/3276790).
Then 
`set :use_sudo, true` on the *deploy.rb* file.
Finally instal

- On the server :

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`

- On the *deploy.rb* (local):

`desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :mkdir, '-p', "#{ release_path }/tmp"
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Note you will also get this error if the deployment server has no disk space!