# Capistrano 3 deploy failed messages - exit status 1 (failed)

Tags: ruby, linux, symfony, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano3

When I deploy my Symfony2 app using Capistrano with symfony gem I get various errors such as

```
Running /usr/bin/env [ -L  /var/www/releases/20151014090151/app/config/parameters.yml ] as ubuntu@ec2-00-000-000-000.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
Command: [ -L /var/www/releases/20151014090151/app/config/parameters.yml ]
Finished in 0.038 seconds with exit status 1 (failed)
```

and I get the same for

```
-f /var/www/releases/20151014120425/app/config/parameters.yml
-L /var/www/releases/20151014090151/web/.htaccess
-L /var/www/releases/20151014090151/web/robots.txt
-L /var/www/releases/20151014090151/app/logs
-d /var/www/releases/20151014120425/app/logs
SYMFONY_ENV=prod /usr/bin/env ln -s /var/www/shared/app/logs /var/www/releases/20151014120425/app/logs
-L /var/www/releases/20151014120425/web/uploads
-d /var/www/releases/20151014120425/web/uploads
-L /var/www/releases/20151014120425/src/Helios/CoreBundle/Resources/translations
-d /var/www/releases/20151014120425/src/Helios/CoreBundle/Resources/translations
-L /var/www/releases/20151014120425/app/spool
-d /var/www/releases/20151014120425/app/spool
-d /var/www/releases/20151014120425/app/cache
```

I am not sure what is failing or what the various flags -f -L -d mean?

The deploy completes but it just shows these failed message. Please can someone advise what they mean and how to fix please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flags are [file test operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

When Capistrano says a command fails, it just means it returns a non-0 status code. In the case of file test operators, it may be checking whether something exists before creating it, so that failure is fed into a conditional which will create the file/folder/symlink. This is normal, albeit confusing. If a critical command fails, Capistrano will stop the deployment and display an error message.

Comment: Thanks. I also now get a zillion errors when I think it is trying to remove the old release folder such as `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/www/releases/20151014113947/vendor/doctrine/inflector/.travis.yml’: Permission denied`

Comment: That's a unix filesystem permissions error. Use ls -l to check permissions and fix them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @will_in_wi I will mark as accepted answer. But I have an update I have put at the end of my question regarding setting permissions too, which I wonder if you could also help with please?

Comment: The user you are deploying as is probably different from the user under which Apache is running. You can probably set up the cache directory as a Capistrano shared directory and set the permissions on the destination appropriately. Additional questions like this should probably go in a new question. Feel free to link back in order to draw my attention if my suggestion doesn't work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @will_in_wi I have posted my new question regarding server permissions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163809/capistrano-3-permissions-not-set-on-correctly-on-cache-and-releases)