# Capistrano 3 permissions not set on correctly on cache and releases

Tags: ruby, linux, symfony, ubuntu-14.04, capistrano3

I am deploying a Symfony2 web application onto Ubuntu 14.04 using [Capistrano 3](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) with [symfony gem](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony). Permissions are not set correctly on the cache folder:
Because I am using the [symfony gem](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony) the permissions should get set on the cache folder and indeed I do see this in the output during deploy which is successful:

```
cd /var/www/releases/20151015083314 && ( SYMFONY_ENV=prod /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv app/cache
```

However when I preview my web app i get the following error in my logs

```
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/releases/20151015082855/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpCache/Store.php on line 40

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/releases/20151015082855/app/cache/staging)\n'
```

I also got permissions errors when removing the releases folder but this seems to have gone away now after I manually removed the oldest folder.

I am deploying with user 'ubuntu'. I have also tried to follow the permissions guide [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions) using the second method of ACL. I set the permissions on the cache folder in /current and on the logs folder in /shared.

My capistrano scripts have the following:

```
# deploy.rb

set :pty, true

set :ssh_options, {
  user: 'ubuntu',
  keys: ['~/.ssh/id_rsa'],
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: ["publickey"]
}

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('app/config/parameters.yml', 'web/.htaccess', 'web/robots.txt')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('app/logs', 'src/Helios/CoreBundle/Resources/translations', 'app/spool')

# staging.rb

server 'ec2-00-000-000-000.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com', user: 'ubuntu', roles: %w{app db web}
```

I am deploying with

```
bundle exec cap staging deploy --trace
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

what is strange is why does the symfony2 app try and create the cache folder within /releases rather than within /current ?

I also followed [this guide](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/symfony2-file-permissions-in-ubuntu/) which worked if I set the permissions after deploy, but then I got the same cache error after a fresh deploy.

**UPDATE**

I have checked again on my server and it it is running as www-data. I did the following

```
APACHE_USER=$(ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}')

echo $APACHE_USER
```

When I deploy with capistrano it is unable to remove the old releases folder. I get multiple lines for each file it can't remove:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘20151029153350/app/cache/staging/.....’: Permission denied
```

The user capistrano is deploying as is 'ubuntu' which is in the 'www-data' group. I have checked the permissions of the releases/20151029153350 directory and it is:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 30 10:13 20151029153350
```

Comment: Is the deploy user ('ubuntu') the same one under which your webserver is running?

Comment: I believe the web server is running under 'www-data' but I'm not sure how to find this out?

Comment: You could use `ps -ef | grep [nameofwebserver]` to see it. Names might be `httpd`, `nginx`, `apache`, et cetera. This would be useful for option 2 in my answer.

Comment: if I do `ps -ef | grep httpd` it returns `ubuntu   14632 14613  0 12:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd`. Id I do `ps -ef | grep apache2` it returns a long list including `ubuntu   14630 14613  0 12:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache2`

Comment: It seems my server was running as user 'ubuntu'. I don't know why? I restarted apache2 using sudo and now it is running as user 'root'. To find this out I ran `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` and it gave me `root     18281  0.0  0.0   8164   912 pts/0    S+   17:48   0:00 egrep --color=auto (apache|httpd)`. Now the web app is writing the cache folder correctly and working after a fresh deploy. Does anyone know how this happened and also why it is not running as user 'www-data'? thanks

Comment: It seems that my production server is running as 'ubuntu' and this is working fine. Does    it matter what my server is running as?

Comment: I have now run this command on the server `APACHE_USER=$(ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}')` and then `echo $APACHE_USER` and it outputs 'www-data'

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you add to your `linked_dirs` an entry for `app/cache` and then create `shared/app/cache` and set its permissions to be accessible by the web server user. This way permissions are retained across deployments.

Alternately, you could use [this plugin](https://github.com/capistrano/file-permissions) to set permissions on the deployed code.

Since `/current` is a symlink to `/releases/[release_timestamp]`, some code will resolve the symlink and access it directly.

Comment: The [Symfony Gem](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony) already has a dependency on [file permissions](https://github.com/capistrano/file-permissions). The Symfony Gem also sets `set :linked_dirs,           [fetch(:log_path), fetch(:web_path) + "/uploads"]`